# Синтаксис перегрузки операторов C#

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов, синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему метод перегружающий оператор должен быть обязательно public и static?

Comment: Что значит "почему"? Такова спецификация. Если вы хотите услышать ответ от разработчиков языка, то их тут не дождетесь. Хотя, со `static` вроде и так понятно

Comment: Почему нельзя обойтись без слова static, ведь чтобы задействовать этот метод, нужен хотя бы один объект этого класса ?

Comment: И почему нельзя сделать метод private или protected?

Comment: [Why are overloaded operators always static in C#?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте создадим тестовый класс и перегрузим оператор сложения для него:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public static MyClass operator +(MyClass A, MyClass B)
    {
        return new MyClass { A = A.A + B.A };
    }
}
```

А теперь посмотрим, какие методы декларирует наш класс:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods();
```

Среди прочего в массиве `methods` мы увидим такую запись:

```
MyClass op_Addition(MyClass, MyClass)
```

Условно, когда вы перегружаете оператор, создается метод с указанным названием и атрибутами `Public | Static | HideBySig | SpecialName`. Так что следующий код:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass { A = 1 };
MyClass b = new MyClass { A = 2 };
MyClass c = a + b;
```

На деле преобразуется в:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass { A = 1 };
MyClass b = new MyClass { A = 2 };
MyClass c = MyClass.op_Addition(a, b);
```

Как видите, когда Вы описали оператор, Вы создали статическую функцию с именем `op_Addition`. Статическая она по той причине, что в `C#` не предусмотрен вариант типа

```
public MyClass operator +(MyClass B)
{
    return new MyClass { A = this.A + B.A };
}
```

Да и это не нужно, так как статическим вариантом можно покрыть любую свою нужду. Так что плодить какие-то дополнительные методы с теми же возможностями - бессмыленно.
Почему синтаксис C# не предусматривает приватные перегруженные операторы? По той же причине, по которой он не поддерживает методы с одинаковыми параметрами, но разными модификаторами доступа: компилятор не сможет понять, какую именно функцию Вы захотите использовать в некотором контексте.

Comment: "он не поддерживает методы с одинаковыми параметрами, но разными модификаторами доступа", почему у нас одинаковые параметры? Можно же создать private метод без public метода.

Comment: @Alex_ Если бы теоретически Вы могли создать таковой метод, Вы бы «закрыли» возможность для создания такового публичного, что неправильно. А вообще, а как уже сказал Андрей, мы сейчас обсуждаем спецификацию языка, так что подобные вопросы правильнее обсуждать с создателями языка, мы можем лишь гадать, почему именно так было сделано) А так, если Вам нужен приватный метод сложения экземпляров Вашего класса, то просто создайте приватный метод Addition)